# How to make endnotes with brackets in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

In a Word document, I insert endnotes, that go at the end of the document.

**How can I have the endnotes with brackets <sup>[1]</sup> like this <sup>[2]</sup> ?**

I have Office Pro Plus 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Reference Tab. There you will get insert Endnote or Footnotes. And this will be placed in the footer of the page. Hope you've got it.

Comment: I know this. This does not make note calls with brackets. Actually, for an endnote, this does not even make the note call with the ¹.

Comment: Do you want something automatic? Can you show an example?